# Как считать трафик через интерфейс?

Tags: tcp-ip, сеть

Например мне надо узнать сколько байт принято/отправлено (tcp) с хоста ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх подключающегося на localhost: port. Как, с чего начинать, где рыть?

Comment: Извиняюсь что не уточнил. Надо написать собственную программу, которая бы считала трафик. Пока использую ipfw для Win,создаю нужные правила и из своей программы считываю и анализирую вывод ipfw show. Но хотелось бы правильное решение, без костылей.

Comment: На каком языке хотите писать?

я писал подобное на Delphi если нужно могу исходники скинуть.

Comment: Мне в принципе все равно, с, с#, delphi. Или у вас реализация чисто на компонентах?

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что приходит на ум, - tcpdump.